# Show MySQL results for words with hebrew vowels?

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation, case-insensitive, hebrew

So in my database I have thousands hebrew words which some have different vowels.

Exmaple: אִלוּלֵא is with vowels.

Example: אלולא is without vowels.

So when I do in MySQL a simple search like:

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `word` = 'אלולא';
```

It won't show me in the result the word with the vowels.

When a user do a more advanced search from this in my website for something, he won't write the word with the vowels, so I need to show them somehow.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

(Btw using ASP.NET for my website).

Comment: You show a SQL query but tagged the question with C# and asp.net. You probably want to use IN comparer.. not =.

Comment: @Jawad well yea there can be a solution somehow using c# maybe also for this? Giving all the options ~.~

Comment: Hum, I wonder if there is a collation that will do that

Comment: Try displaying some words with `SELECT word, HEX(word)`. I believe you'll see that the pointed words have extra Unicode characters for the vowels. I don't believe there is a MySql collation that can compare pointed words with unpointed. You'll have to store the unpointed form to search.

Comment: Use `WHERE` with either the `LIKE` operator or the `REGEXP` one?

Comment: @JosefZ I tried, in JS I can do it using REGEX Replace with "[\u0591-\u05C7]/g", I tried playing with it on MySql, didn't manage to make it work. I think in MySql the method works differently.

Comment: Maybe `where word REGEXP pattern` (here `pattern` could be something like `א[\u0591-\u05C7]*ל[\u0591-\u05C7]*ו[\u0591-\u05C7]*ל[\u0591-\u05C7]*א` for given word). I don't speak Hebrew so constructed pattern may be inaccurate. Replace Unicode subrange with a string literal if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the column to `utf8_hungarian_ci` did the trick for it to work.

```
ALTER TABLE words MODIFY COLUMN word VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL;
```